# Customize SharePoint:FormFields to a specific height

Tags: css, sharepoint-designer

I'm customizing a NewForm.aspx page and I've created a few new SharePoint:FormFields in the form of textboxes. I'm looking to customize the height of these boxes on a case-by-case basis, but I can't figure it out.

I've looked into DisplaySize, but that only controls the width of a specific textboxe, and I've seen adding in:

```
style> .ms-long{width:100px;} </style>
```

but that changes every SharePoint:FormField size, not just one.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using jQuery. With jQuery you can query dom elements (ie. fields) by an attribute of your choice (e.g. the attribute title) and the manipulate it. See Jan Tielens Series about integrating SharePoint and jQuery. http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/11/20/sharepoint-2007-and-jquery-1.aspx 
Or just google sharepoint + jquery.